# Developer mode Chrome extension notifications works on one computer but not on another

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

One one Macbook Pro(box_working) with chrome version 84.0 the below extension works but on another Macbook Pro(box_not_working) with chrome version 85.0 it does not. Note that these extensions are being loaded directly from the two devices(not from the extension store). The iconUrl path used for creating the notification is correct as well.

On both devices, The callback for the chrome.notification.create is invoked and the log message "notification sent" from the callback shows up. However the notification never appears on box_working and on box_not_working it always appears.

On box_not_working, notifications fo get fired from extensions installed from the extension store. It appears to be only the dev mode extensions loaded from the device that do not work.

Below is the manifest.json and the background.js used. The notification is meant to fire each time a tab is updated for the test.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

The background.js is

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {

  console.log("on updated listener");
  options = {
    title: 'Notification test',
    message: 'How great it is!',
    iconUrl: '/icon.png',
    type: 'basic'
  };
  chrome.notifications.create('', options, function(notificationId) {
    console.log("notification sent");
  });
});
```

The icon.png is at the same level as the 'js' directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure if the notification is not turned off in these places
1- On Chrome, clicking on the three dots -> settings -> privacy&security -> site settings -> notifications
2- On mac top right corner, there is a hamburger, click and go to the wheel icon on the bottom right corner, make sure the chrome notification is turned on.